# Chrome extension, how to Modify page content (add something)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extension development, my first project (to learn) is to create an extension that adds some html to another website's existing page.

I plan on creating a 'page' action which fires for a page with a certain URL...

Has anyone seen a tutorial like this, or do you know of an API for adding html to a page?

Answer (score 4):

You can find some example at [Google Sample Extension page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#page-action-by-url), however your question seems better answered on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069119/946550).

Comment: The linked question is too old and chrome extension version 2 does not allow that modification.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of sample extensions on the [Chrome extension API site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples). There are a couple of `browserAction` examples that will be almost identical to using `pageAction`.