# Modify HTML of loaded pages using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I add some HTML code to the loaded page if page's title contains specific text?

Chrome extensions are new grounds to me and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

### References:

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

You can take the following code as a reference for adding some HTML Code.

#### `manifest.json`

This file registers content script to extension.

```
{
"name":"Inject DOM",
"description":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068879",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.co.in/*","https://www.google.co.in/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### `myscript.js`

A trivial script for adding a button to `Google` page

```
// Checking page title
if (document.title.indexOf("Google") != -1) {
    //Creating Elements
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    //Appending to DOM 
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

### `Output`

You see a button added to a desired page

[image]

Comment: Could someone elaborate on how to go from those two files --> to a local extension file --> to an installed extension?

Comment: @Luke use a template like this one : https://github.com/Ehesp/Chrome-Extension-Twitter-Bootstrap-3-Template

Comment: For developing I found the solution was to go to chrome://extensions, check the box for Developer mode, then Load unpacked extension, and select the directory that contains the files.

Comment: fyi, DOM is not HTML, if your intentions are to get some HTML from the web-server, and just before it is being parsed into DOM and shows in the browser, to edit it, this is the wrong answer to you.. keep Googling around...

Comment: How would we modify existing content on an HTML page?

Answer (score 11):

@Sudarshan 's answer explains page specificity, Great, but what about the comments added? here's how to do what he missed in an easier more practical manner
to modify existing content or to create content on an page the easiest method would be:

> Modify

single item modification:

```
document.getElementById("Id").innerHtml = this.innerHtml + "<some code here>";
```

or to modify attributes:

```
document.getElementById("Id").class = "classname";

//or ->

document.getElementById("Id").style.color = "#a1b2c3";
```

for adding multiple lines of code do the following:

```
document.getElementById("Id").innerHtml = this.innerHtml + `
 <some code here>                                                            <!-- Line 1 -->
 and we're on multiple lines!` + "variables can be inserted too!" + `        <!-- Line 2 -->
 <this code will be inserted directly **AS IS** into the DOM                 <!-- Line 3 -->
`
;
```

- but now  what about easy element insertation?

> Create

large code injection (example from coding project done a while back) see [insertAdjacentHtml API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) :

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

bod.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
    <div class="Boingy" id="Boingy">
        <div class="Boihead" id="BoiHead">
            <div class="deXBox" id="deXBox">
                <div class="Tr-Bl_Button" style="height: 25px;width: 2px;margin-left: 11.65px;background-color: gray;transform: rotate(45deg);-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);Z-index: 1;">
                    <div class="Tl-Br_Button" style="height: 25px;width: 2px;background-color: gray;transform: rotate(90deg);-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);Z-index: 2;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <embed id="IframeThingyA" src="` + "url" + `" type="text/html">
            </embed>
        </div>
    `);
```

references:

- [insert - Adjacent - Html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [content specific code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396634/chrome-extension-run-for-a-specific-page)