# Chrome - load specific link with window.open(this.href)

Tags: php, google-chrome

On a website ( not mine, I don't have acces to the servers ), on a specific page, there is something like this :

```
<a href="link" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">name</a>
```

I want a different link there, adress which I edit with the Chrome Dev Tools. Can I somehow save this change and when I access that specific page, the edited page will load instead ( maybe from cache or something ? ) and it will contain the modified link, not the original one ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You could write a Chrome extension to do this.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please give more details about how should I do that ?

Comment: That's a very broad question, not really suitable for this site. Search for Chrome extension tutorials.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Nevertheless, thank you for helping me. I also found this ( relevant to what I want to do ) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068879/modify-html-of-loaded-pages-using-chrome-extensions