# Chrome extension to modify the contents of a page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, title

I am interested in creating a Chrome extension which can manipulate some of the content of specific webpages..

I want to replace something like this:

```
<td class="Data">Phone:</td>
```

with something like this:

```
<span title="Telephone number including area code."><td class="Data">Phone:</td></span>
```

The reason for this is to add hover-over or tool-tip text to certain parts of an existing website.

Is this possible with a Chrome extension? If so, how could this be done? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify html of loaded pages using chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068879/modify-html-of-loaded-pages-using-chrome-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Chrome extension, but even easier would be a bookmarklet.

Basically, the browser allows you to run javascript in the address bar in the form javascript://your valid javascript.

So write the script to achieve your desired results, minify it to a single line, then bookmark the results. It can then also be used in any browser.

I don't understand the exact use case, and your html is not valid, but you could do something similar pretty easily, this example assumes jquery is available:

```
javascript:$(function(){ $('td:contains("Phone")').attr('title', 'Telephone number including area code'); });
```

Note: the :contains() selector is *case-sensitive*