# Replace Tab Name Chrome C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, browser

i want to replace the tab name on my chrome. i have managed to get it detect the tab using this code

```
public void FetchProcess()
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

    if (processes.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Process item in processes)
        {
            int milliseconds = 100;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
            if (item.MainWindowTitle.Contains("YouTube - Google Chrome"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yayy");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But cannot get it to rename the tab. I have tried replacing it but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do what @avigloz said! An extension for chrome is not that hard to create. Check this out [How to start with chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

> An easier way would be to make a Chrome extension for changing the page title, but that may not be what you're looking for.

If you just want to rename the process:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);
```

Usage:

```
if (!chromeProcess.HasExited)
    SetWindowText(chromeProcess.MainWindowHandle, "New title");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to inject code into the actual page, to change the contents of the `<title>` tag.

This is fairly non-trivial to do from outside Chrome itself. An easier way would be to make a [Chrome extension for changing the page title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068879/modify-html-of-loaded-pages-using-chrome-extensions), but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: How Would i do this?