# create google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to write google chrome extension code. but what I want to do is read the data of a site and intervene according to that data. For example, if a product is on sale on Amazon, if I type it with a command, will it automatically get it? I would like to emphasize that I will not take it, it has to take it automatically with the command I gave, so will it be able to take it by itself while I sleep? Is this possible with a java script?

"Edited again"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible.

I found 2 resources that you should read up on for this type of this type of thing:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/ (Get started and learn how extensions work)

[Modify HTML of loaded pages using chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068879/modify-html-of-loaded-pages-using-chrome-extensions/14069119#14069119) (Manifest V2, maybe look around for something similar in V3?)