# Can a browser extension be used to add custom fields?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am looking for a solution to use browser extension that could add custom fields for data input on an existing, externally hosted web application.

These fields would need to be displayed, completed by a user and answers added to API call to be loaded to my database.

Is this possible or does it require integration with the application that hosts the existing page?

Comment: It depends on that app. Might be possible. Or not. No one knows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add custom fields to a form/page.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838418/chrome-extension-how-to-modify-page-content-add-something) question for some ideas.

No, for most cases you cannot integrate those new fields with for example a post request **unless**  the server is expecting those fields and if there isn't validation on the expected API parameters.

Without knowing about your API or server side code no one will be able answer 100%.  Short answer is that you are better & safer off modifying the server side application directly.